# input_shape in LSTM

Tags: keras, neural-network, time-series, lstm

I have the following code snippet:

```
    X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1]))
    X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1]))


    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(200, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[2]), return_sequences=False))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32)
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4
```

The original shapes of X_train and X_test:

```
X_train: 1483, 13
X_test: 360, 13
```

and after reshaping they become:

```
X_train: 1483, 1, 13
X_test: 360, 1, 13
```

I know this might be a duplicate, but none of the answers online seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

`input_shape=(X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[2])` is wrong.

An LSTM should have 2D input shapes (which means 3D internal tensors).
l
- The input shape must contain `(sequence_length, features_per_step)`.
- This means the internal shape will be `(free_batch_size, sequence_length, features_per_step)`

Your data then must be 3D, ok, but the `input_shape` should be 2D.
Now, `sequence_length` is absolutely necessary for a recurrent layer to work, if you have `sequence_length = 1` it's totaly useless, unless you are going for `stateful=True` which involves much more complicated code.